# ionic cordova build android --prod --release gives error using with ionic2-date-picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ionic2

When I run the following command in my project where I have used the ionic2-date-picker I am getting an error.

Command to build to android:
`ionic cordova build android --prod`

Error:

> [WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin ().
>   Error: Unexpected value 'DatePicker in
>   /Users/tharindu/Downloads/Projects/mastersLoyalty/node_modules/ionic2-date-picker/date-picker.component.d.ts'
>   declared by the module 'AppModule
>   in/Users/tharindu/Downloads/Projects/mastersLoyalty/src/app/app.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@component annotation.

Comment: can you add `app.module.ts` to the question?

Comment: DatePicker Added in declarations and entryComponents

Comment: Looks like an [open issue](https://github.com/shangyilim/ionic2-date-picker/issues/17)

Comment: I got the solution now. Have a look below steps.

Step 1 - Download and extract this component.
Step 2 - Rename the lib folder to ionic2-date-picker.
Step 3 - Copy and Paste the renamed folder to your ionic app component folder.
Step 2 - Now this component you can use like local component
EX: import { DatePicker } from '../../components/ionic2-date-picker/date-picker.component';

Remaining code as same.

Comment: you could answer your question and accept then instead of commenting